# Navigation 'App.DbModel.IssueCategory (Dictionary<string, object>).Tickets' was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was attempting migrations and ran into the following error:

> Navigation 'App.DbModel.IssueCategory (Dictionary<string, object>).Tickets' was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it.

The Ticket model:

```
public partial class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public long? IssueCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string? Issue { get; set; }
   
    public string? AssignedTo { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    public int? DateResolved { get; set; }

    public bool Solved { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Aspnetuser))]
    public string? UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Aspnetuser? AssignedToNavigation { get; set; }

    public virtual IssueCategory? IssueCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual Aspnetuser? User { get; set; }
}
```

The IssueCategory model:

```
public partial class IssueCategory
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string? Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } = new List<Ticket>();
}
```

Issue category in dbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IssueCategory>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PRIMARY");

        entity.ToTable("issue_category");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnType("bigint(20)")
            .HasColumnName("id");
        entity.Property(e => e.Category).HasMaxLength(95);
        entity.HasMany(e => e.Tickets)
            .WithOne(e => e.IssueCategory)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.IssueCategoryId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.Id);
    });
```

Ticket in dbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>(entity =>
    {
        entity
            .HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PRIMARY");
        entity.ToTable("ticket");

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.IssueCategoryId, "IssueCategoryId");

        entity.Property(e => e.AssignedTo)
            .HasMaxLength(95)
            .HasColumnName("AssignedTo");
        entity.Property(e => e.DateCreated)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("'NULL'")
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasColumnName("DateCreated");
        entity.Property(e => e.DateResolved)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("'NULL'")
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("DateResolved");
        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("Id");
        entity.Property(e => e.Issue)
            .HasMaxLength(95) // Adjust the maximum length as needed
            .HasColumnName("Issue");
       
        entity.Property(e => e.IssueCategoryId)
            .HasColumnType("bigint(20)")
            .HasColumnName("IssueCategoryId");
        entity.Property(e => e.Solved).HasColumnName("Solved");
        entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
            .HasMaxLength(95)
            .HasColumnName("UserId");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.IssueCategory).WithMany(e => e.Tickets)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.IssueCategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .HasConstraintName("IssueCategoryId");

        entity.Navigation(e => e.IssueCategory);
        entity.HasOne(t => t.AssignedToNavigation)
          .WithMany(u => u.TicketAssignedToNavigations)
          .HasForeignKey(t => t.AssignedTo)
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    });
```